# Angular @material/layout-grid

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, grid-layout

I want to use material-components and size them with layout-grid. Is it the right approach? I use @material/layout-grid package, but when I try to do something like this(side bar 8 columns, content 4 columns):

```
<div class="mdc-layout-grid">
<mat-drawer-container class="mdc-layout-grid__inner">
  <mat-drawer mode="side" opened class="mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-8">Drawer content</mat-drawer>
  <mat-drawer-content class="mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-4">Main content</mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>
</div>
```

Component's style overrides grid rules. Tell me please, what can I use to make a layout with the angular material?

Comment: The most popular responsive layout library for Angular is [Angular Flex-Layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout).